# Can I call a Python function without brackets, like a shell command. If so, how?

Tags: python, function, terminal, terminal-emulator

First time posting here, so apologies if I don't follow formatting guidelines or anything.

I'm writing a terminal-like utility tool for, among other things, bulk file editing. My goal was to have every function be three letters ling, a bit like in Assembly. For example, `mkd("yeet")` makes a directory called yeet.
The basic way it works is as follows: I define a whole bunch of functions, and then I set up a `while True` loop, that prints the `eval()` of whatever I type.
So far, everything's going pretty well, except for one thing. I want to be able to call functions without having to add the brackets. Any parameters should be added afterwards, like using `sys.argscv[1]`.

Here is a [link to the GitHub repo](https://github.com/WalrusGumboot/sim-terminal).

Is this possible in Python, if so, how?

Obviously, just typing the name of the function will return me `<function pwd at 0x7f6c4d86f6a8>` or something along those lines.

Thanks in advance,
Walrus Gumboot

Comment: You should almost **never** use `eval(input())`! That will allow the user to do many bad things (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice, https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: I think you're going about it the wrong way. You should parse the input string and check it's valid by doing string comparisons and then call the appropriate function (or return an error message).

Comment: Just to clarify; you're not asking how to call a function without paranthesis in Python, but how a user could type in `mdk yeet` into your program?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Exactly. Also, can I make `eval()` safer by adding `{'__builtins__':None}, {}` or does this make no difference?

Comment: I would suggest not using `eval` at all, as it will guide you towards both security issues and performance issues. A better approach would be to take the input from the user and parse it yourself, then checking if that method exists.

Comment: Agreed. The cmd module exists for exactly this purpose, and it's much safer. See example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example if you want to parse the string yourself, that's easily extendable.

```
def mkd(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        print("Making", *args)
    else:
        print("mdk only takes 1 argument.")

def pwd(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        print("You're here!")
    else:
        print("pwd doesn't take any arguments.")

def add(*args):
    if len(args) == 2:
        if args[0].isdigit() and args[1].isdigit(): 
            print("Result:", int(args[0]) + int(args[1]))
        else:
            print("Can only add two numbers!")
    else:
        print("add takes exactly 2 arguments.")

def exit(*args):
    quit()


functions = {'mkd': mkd, 'pwd': pwd, 'add': add, 'exit': exit}  # The available functions.  

while True:
    command, *arguments = input("> ").strip().split(' ')  # Take the user's input and split on spaces.
    if command not in functions:
        print("Couldn't find command", command)
    else:
        functions[command](*arguments)
```

Comment: @WalrusGumboot Do note however that the arguments are just strings, which means you have to do some error handling if you need to convert them to integers (which eval did automatically). Either surround the statement in a try-catch, or check that the arguments really are numbers before converting them. Added an example in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) or [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) depending the scope and and pass the string you get in the arguments:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print("Hi from foo!")
... 
>>> locals()["foo"]()
Hi from foo!
```

Where `"foo"` would be the `sys.args[1]` from the call to `python script.py foo`

Or you can define your own dictionary with the available commands, for example:

**`calc.py`**

```
commands = {
    "add" : lambda x, y: x + y,
    "mul" : lambda x, y: x * y,
}

if __name__ == __main__:
    import sys
    _, command, arg1, arg2, *_ = sys.args
    f = commands.get(command, lambda *_: "Invalid command")
    res = f(int(arg1), int(arg2))
    print(res)
```

Calling `python calc.py add 5 10`

Comment: Can I also use this with, say, `eval(input(">"))` and type add 5 120 to get in this case 125? If so, this solves my problem perfectly

Comment: you can simply use: `args = input(">").split(" ")` to get a list of the arguments separated by space

Comment: Just tested it out, worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, no, you do need the brackets to call a function.

You might find the [cmd](https://pymotw.com/3/cmd/) module helpful, though - it's intended for writing interactive command line tools like you're describing, and you'd have a lot more flexibility as to the input format.

Using `cmd`, you tool might look like:

```py
import cmd, os

class MyTerminalLikeUtilityTool(cmd.Cmd):

    def do_mkd(self, line):
        os.makedirs(line)

    def do_EOF(self, line):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyTerminalLikeUtilityTool().cmdloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The [click library](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) is a library that i have used and in my opinion, perfect for creating commandline applications. Here is a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNke39OZ2k0) showing how to create an example application.

[Here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/why/#why-not-argparse) is an explanation from the site on how click does not use `argeparse`.

Comment: Does this library support interactive sessions? That's what the OP is looking for, I think.

Comment: @brunns yes it does

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. There's no valid syntax having the form

```
f 1 2
```

in python. You need either a language that supports that (eg. Scala) or a language that has macros (eg. lisp/clojure)

The closest thing you could do is eg, make the function a callable object, overload the binary shift operator, and write something like

```
f << 1, 2
```